# Hidden pixels in PNG

Tags: c#, svg, png, pixel

[image]I'm designing a C# console application that converts Bitmap into Vector Art (SVG) by looping through pixels, then get the pixel color in order to draw and fill the corresponding vector art component with this color .

The issue I'm facing is , when i loop through pixels to get their colors using this code

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imagePath);
for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
   {
      currentFill = img.GetPixel(x, y).Name ;
   }
 }
```

at some x and y i get a black color (#afafaf) that does not actually exist in the image (or can't be seen with naked eye) !
this issue did not happen with jpg or tiff formats for instance..any ideas ?

Comment: `#afafaf` is light gray.

Comment: can you post the image? As Duopixel said, it is a light gray, and if it is only one pixel thick your might not see it.

Comment: sorry my mistake it is afafafa

Comment: i added a png image in my post please check it out  ,  the pixel of x ==1 and y ==3 is of afafafa color

Comment: Where do you get these hex values from? they really ought to have either 6 or with alpha channel 8 hex digits. so maybe it really is `0a fa fa fa` an almost transparent light gray? Which is precisly what the pixel you talk about has, according to photoshop r=g=b=250

Comment: Actually this is the value i get from my C# code debugger !

Answer (score 0):

PNG files can have an Alpha channel.  The `color` type has an `A` property that represents Alpha (transparency).

Comment: are there some kinds of calculations needed to set a proper value for alpha channel ??